# filter on the latest record of a one to many collection in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy

I have the following sqlalchemy models

```
class Alert(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'alerts'


    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    alert_text = Column(Text)


    @hybrid_property
    def latest_state(self):
        if self.state_changes:
            return self.state_changes[-1]

        return self.state_changes


class AlertStateChange(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'alert_state_change'
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name='pk_alert_state_change'),
    )

    id = Column(Integer)
    reason_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('reasons.id'))
    alert_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Alert.id))
    reason = relationship('Reason', backref='state_changes')
    alert = relationship(Alert, backref='state_changes')
    status = Column(Text)
    date = Column(DateTime)



class Reason(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'reasons'
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name='pk_reason'),

    )

    id = Column(Integer)
    reason_text = Column(Text)
```

So basically an alert has a state that is edited with a reason. When a state changes user also enters a comment and the info on who user issued the change is also kept but i have excluded those two fields for simplicity. Status can be either `open` or `closed` and when a user open an alert no reason is needed thus reason_id can be  null.

I want to be able to filter alerts that are currently closed with a specific reason text but cannot find the correct joins.

E.g I would start with this

```
session.query(Alert).join(AlertStateChange).join(Reason).filter(Reason.reason_text=='wanted reason)
```

but this would bring me all alerts that some time in the past or now were closed with a 'wanted reason'. How can I filter using only the current state (thus the latest record for each alert)

Comment: `q = ...filter(Reason.reason_text=='wanted reason')` then `q.filter(AlertStateChange.state='somestate').all()` ?

Comment: Wouldn't that bring all alerts that at some point had the status 'somestate'  but not necessarily  their latest status?

Comment: How do you define a laststate? By time or? You can filter that query again for the state which you want

Comment: latest status is the last status changed that occured thus the most recent record for each alert

Comment: @Apostolos Did you ever get a slick solution for this?